# Case of an external list being inaccessible

Tags: 2013, external-list, bdc

I have an external list that I created with a bdc, but it might happen that the external source is not available is there any way that the sharepoint saves a last access? if not what is the best alternative since I need the information on that list < key, value > for a Dropdown-list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an unreliable data source is not a good basis for leveraging ECT.
I would suggest caching the data to a more persistent location like a SQL Table or a SharePoint List (if the dataset is not large).

If you have SQL Server, you could develop an SSIS package for this quite quickly and run it as a scheduled job.

HTH.

Comment: it probably won't be a unreliable source but they are asking me to have safe check just in case. it's a really small amount of data but it's in other system that might be updated. How would you do this with a sharepoint list?

Comment: If you meant how would you cache data in a list, then just write a SharePoint timer job to sync the external data source with the list. 

Also, if you begin the sentence above with the word "probably" then it implicitly means that the data source IS unreliable.

Comment: Yes! what I meant by probably is that we are now accessing it through a vpn, but as soon as everything is moved to production they'll be on the same network. but really appreciate your help thank you.  I believe now I have enought information to research better and being new to sharepoint really doesn't help. Thank you!

Comment: @Opetion I have released a screencast for writing timer jobs [here](http://www.screencast.com/t/0on273cM). Code samples are [here](https://github.com/shailensukul/SharePoint.Presentations.TimerJob)
HTH

Comment: Congrats! and thanks for taking the time to do such a thing. It was kind of a few months ago I didn't even remembered this post x) But it is great for future references